# Icinga Web no hosts/services showing up

Tags: icinga

After a fresh install of icinga 1.8 and icinga web I've added a few hosts/services and restarted the icinga service. Next I cleared the cache in icinga web through the web interface by clicking on admin at the top of the screen and clear cache. then reloaded the icinga-web interface and the newly added host/services were not displayed.

The icinga logs do not show any issues, I've also run `/etc/init.d/icinga showerrors` and no errors or warnings displayed.

I've searched everywhere for a solution and I've read all the documentation from icinga but haven't found any references to this issue anywhere.

Comment: I raised the question on the IRC channel and the first questions are "Do you use ido2db?" "If so, is the database running?" "If so, are new hosts appearing in the database?"

Comment: there's a dedicated wiki page to cover most of the things you can and should do in such cases. https://wiki.icinga.org/display/testing/Icinga+Web+Testing

Comment: Just for completeness I had a similar issue and found the solution here: http://serverfault.com/questions/334070/icinga-web-doesnt-update-when-i-change-configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icinga-web doesn't update when i change configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/334070/icinga-web-doesnt-update-when-i-change-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the whether the web user has access to view the hosts/services that you've added. This can be set using the Icinga roles. For icinga2 have a look at `/etc/icingaweb2/roles.ini`. The [link](https://icinga.com/docs/icingaweb2/latest/doc/06-Security/) has more information.

For icinga classic web locate `cgi.cgi` inside icinga web root and add the new user to `authorized_for_*` directives wherever you want to allow the user access.

Answer (score 0):

Would check indeed if Ido Database is up and running and correctly configured in `/etc/icinga2/features-enabled.`

Also that might be a case where the database schema has been updated between the 2 versions and you want to run the migration script [for MySQL](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/16-upgrading-icinga-2/#upgrading-mysql-db)