# icinga-web not updating icinga status properly

Tags: nagios, icinga

I have a problem similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/334070/icinga-web-doesnt-update-when-i-change-configuration)... if you look at the photo there, you'll see that the icinga server is marked as down.

I checked everything according to the answer given there, but it has already been done - and I'm seeing new hosts and services whenever I add them. But the icinga monitor is not being updated.

The `cgi.cfg` has this line in it:

`icinga_check_command=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nagios -F /var/lib/icinga/status.dat -e 5 -C '/usr/sbin/icinga'`

Running the command produces this:

`# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nagios -F /var/lib/icinga/status.dat -e 5 -C '/usr/sbin/icinga'
NAGIOS OK: 6 processes, status log updated 1 second ago`

I went to `/etc/icinga-web/` and looked around, but didn't find any appropriate settings.

I checked the `ido2utils` and restarted them just in case - but they've been running.

How do I fix this? Everything else is working ok, but not the icinga server status in the summary.

**EDIT** I was remiss in not mentioning that I am using Ubuntu Trusty Server on an amd64 machine. The installed icinga instance is from the Repositories.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing Classic UI and Web here. They use different data source backends and configuration files.

Classic UI parses the status.dat abd objects.cache files which are periodically written by the core. The nain configuration parts happen in cgi.cfg.

Icinga Web 1.x reads its data from the IDO database being populated by the ido2db daemon which receives its data from the idomod event broker in Icinga Core 1.x (note: Icinga 2 features such as ido-mysql directly write into the IDO database, ido2db is incompatible to that). Web 1.x configuration happens in its xml files beneath /etc/icinga-web.

There are some possible problems rendering the icinga_programstatus table updates 'down' in Icinga Web 1.x:

- either the core isn't writing to idomod
- ido2db not running, or no connection from idomod
- php timezone issue with server timezone with a wrong offset

More on such topics is covered here: https://wiki.icinga.org/display/testing/Icinga+Web+Testing#IcingaWebTesting-NoData 
https://wiki.icinga.org/display/testing/Special+IDOUtils+Queries
http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/icinga-web-config.html#configweb-timezone